# Sorting entries in Ruby on Rails 4 index by date/time, not order of input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

This is my Rails 4 app: http://wheels2015.herokuapp.com

I want the entries (events) to be listed in chronological order, as opposed to the order in which I entered them into the database (as they are currently).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524165/ruby-on-rails-railscast-213-calendar-sort-by-datetime-not-date) isn't the same as mine, but it appears to be in the general ballpark, so when a user suggested that OP look up the ActiveRecord query methods in the Rails API (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order) I did.

Do you think this would do what I want it to?

```
Event.order('date_time')
=> SELECT "events".* FROM "event" ORDER BY event_date_time
```

This is the portion of my event controller that's responsible for the `index` page, as well as the `event params`:

```
 def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:event_name, :location, :description, :event_date_time, :organizer, :category) if params[:event]
    end 

  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end
```

Comment: Well, why don't you try it? I don't understand the question. Do you want me to run the code for you and tell you that it works? Because your app could do the same thing for you.

Comment: is `event_date_time` the same as `created_at`? `created_at` is the timestamp when you created the entry. i think you want `Event.order('created_at')`

Comment: @rob i've added a specific field for a date and time that's different. I **don't** want it to sort in order of `created_at`, which I suspect it already does because my latest entry is last even though it will take place before several other entries I made.

Comment: I'm not sure how this question isn't answered by Rails docs and/or tutorials.

Comment: `@events = Event.order('event_date_time') => SELECT "events".* FROM "event" ORDER BY event_date_time` gives me a syntax error, so I tried plain old `@events = Event.order('event_date_time')` and it works! thanks, I think just the act of writing out the question has helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I had some minor trouble understanding the documentation, but this did what I wanted:

`events_controller.rb`:

```
  def index
    @events = Event.order('event_date_time')
  end
```

I swear I didn't ask this question so that I could answer it 5 minutes later; it's more like the action of writing the question helped me think through it? I don't want anyone to make the effort to write an answer, but if someone else is already in the process of working on one i'd upvote theirs instead of my own.